# PL/SQL dynamically assign fields

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I got a problem to solve and I don't know how to do it.

I'm using a Oracle 10g Database to import five types of files. This files are in CSV format.
I know that in File 1 the field name is in the 1st position, in the 2nd file I know the field name is in the 4 position...and so on. Basically the same field is in all files but in different positions.
I import the files to a table in database (let's call this x_table) with fields like ipl_c1, ipl_c2, ipl_c3...

I got this in information of the fields position in database table, per file (let's call it x_param_table).
Now I got to migrate this data into different tables (one table per file type).
My problem is: I got to make a procedure to treat each file? This is possible to do dynamically?

What I'm doing is, I create a type based on the destiny table like this:

```
i_table destiny_table%rowtype; 
i_source_table x_table%rowtype;
```

next i iterate the table where the records are (`i_source_table`), but in a different procedure per file.

If I'm in file 1 then i

```
i_table(i).name := i_source_table(idx).ipl_c1
```

if I'm in file 2 then i

```
i_table(i).name := i_source_table(idx).ipl_c4
```

since I got the positions of the field in database (x_param_table) and cannot do something like

```
i_table(i).name := i_source_table(idx).ipl_c||x_param_table.position
```

Maybe I'm seeing this the wrong way...but I belive is possible to do this in one procedure.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider converting the source table as XMLTYPE, so that you are able to dynamically get the value for a specific column. In this way you only need to define very few procedures to accomplish the requirement.

For example:

```
DECLARE
    SRC XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    SRC := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM < 5');
    FOR R IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(SRC, '/ROWSET/ROW')))) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objet name: ' || R.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('/ROW/OBJECT_NAME/text()')
                             .GETSTRINGVAL);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The fifth column value is: ' || R.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('/ROW/*[5]/text()')
                             .GETSTRINGVAL);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The output is:

```
Objet name: ICOL$
The fifth column value is: TABLE
Objet name: TAB$
The fifth column value is: TABLE
Objet name: I_USER2
The fifth column value is: INDEX
Objet name: I_CCOL2
The fifth column value is: INDEX
```

There are several ways to convert a select statement into xml --  xmltype(cursor(...)), dbms_xmlquery, etc.

You can even update the dest table with dbms_xmlsave and dbms_xmlstore instead of insert or update statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view for each import file, e.g.

```
create or replace view file_1 as
select ipl_c1, ipl_c3, ipl_c2, ipl_c5, ipl_c4
from x_table;

create or replace view file_2 as
select ipl_c5, ipl_c2, ipl_c1, ipl_c3, ipl_c4
from x_table;

create or replace view file_3 as
select ipl_c3, ipl_c1, ipl_c2, ipl_c4, ipl_c5
from x_table;

etc.
```

Then you can do simple inserts into these views. Each file uses the associated view:

```
For file type #1
insert into file_1 values (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 ,col_5);

For file type #2
insert into file_2 values (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 ,col_5);

etc.
```

Then you don't have to shuffle around your columns.